# Запрос на удаленное API при разработке с локальной машины

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

Как при локальной разработке на связке NodeJS/ReactJS/Webpack правильно обращаться к удаленному API для получения данных?

Сейчас запросы не проходят с 401 ошибкой (кроссдоменный запрос).

Как правильно обойти эту проблему?

Comment: Вариант 1. Вы обращаетесь с клиента (веб страницы) к API к которому надо обращаться со стороны сервера/backend
Вариант 2. Вы обращаетесь не к тому API (не доступен публично). Он проверяет источник запроса/аутентификацию и не дает доступ

Comment: @pvkovalev да, я обращаюсь с бэка, но какое значение это имеет? можно настроить прокси сервер? если есть данные входа на АПИ?

Comment: Значение? Ну обычно кросс-доменные запросы запрещены по соображениям безопасности. Так просто из JavaScript на странице одного домена данные из друго домена не дернуть.В вашем случае кажется проблема в API, но без большего количества деталей сказать мне сказать что-то трудно.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо на стороне API настроить CORS (как раз таки кроссдоменные запросы).
По умолчанию они отключены в целях безопасности.
Включить их можно как для определённых доменов, так и для всех.
Если API так же написан на NodeJS, то вот вариант решения:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, PUT, UPDATE, HEAD, OPTIONS, GET, POST");
  next();
});
```